# Double ASC in MySQL Command

Tags: mysql, sql

Why can't I run this MySQL command?

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE
    id = 1 OR
    id BETWEEN 2 AND 8
GROUP BY
    username ASC
ORDER BY
    username ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Can anyone explain it?

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '= 1 OR id BETWEEN 2 AND 8 GROUP BY username ASC
ORDER BY username ASC LIMIT 5' at line 1
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Don't be shy.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1 OR id BETWEEN 2 AND 8 GROUP BY username ASC ORDER BY username ASC LIMIT 5' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = 1 OR id BETWEEN 2 AND 8
GROUP BY username ASC
ORDER BY username ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

The error that you are getting is because `id` is treated as an alias for `users` and MySQL is expecting something like `,`, `[LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, CROSS] JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `LIMIT`.

The `ORDER BY` is redundant in MySQL (at least most versions), because the `ASC`  in the `GROUP BY` does the sorting (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)).  However, I would not depend on that, and use:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = 1 OR id BETWEEN 2 AND 8
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY username ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe i need sleep to decrease my fatigue

Answer (score 1):

just add `where` before your condition, also remove ASC after group by it is no sense:

```
SELECT * FROM users where id = 1 
OR id BETWEEN 2 AND 8 
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user ASC LIMIT 5
```